# Boolean simplification to OR expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I noticed that $$\bar{B}C + B\bar{C} + BC$$ is equivalent to $$B + C$$

but I wasn't sure how I could use boolean algebra to simplify this down. I think it has to do with factoring out a term to get $$(\bar{B} + B)$$ which then equals 1, but I'm not quite sure.

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $X = X+X$ so you have $\bar{B}C  + B\bar{C} + BC = \bar{B}C + BC + B\bar{C} + BC = (\bar{B}C + BC) + (B\bar{C} + BC) = C+B$.

Comment: @copper.hat You might as well put that into an answer.